# Formatting google chart area date( like Mar 2012, Oct 2013 etc)

Tags: google-visualization, date-format, linechart

I want to show Google Chart Area date as Mar 2012, Oct 2013 etc. There should not be any date digits in the format. I can only find 3 formats as

### formats

var formatter_long = new google.visualization.DateFormat({formatType: 'long'});

var formatter_medium = new google.visualization.DateFormat({formatType: 'medium'});

var formatter_short = new google.visualization.DateFormat({formatType: 'short'});

### Resulting in to

February 28, 2008 (long)

Feb 28, 2008 (medium)

2/28/08 (short)

long and medium work for me if I can remove date digits from the result. Is there a chance to do it somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google uses a subset of the [ICU SimpleDateFormat standard](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classSimpleDateFormat.html#_details).

If you mean "remove date digits" as in "remove the day and display just month/year" then you could format the string as follows:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2012,1,5)],
    [new Date(2012,2,10)],
    [new Date(2012,3,15)],
    [new Date(2012,4,20)]
  ]);

  alert(data.getFormattedValue(3,0));

  var formatter1 = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'yyyy, MMM'});

  formatter1.format(data,0);

  alert(data.getFormattedValue(3,0));
}
```

When you define the data table, the first alert will list the formatted date as "May 20, 2012". Once you apply the formatter, it will read "May, 2012" only. I think this is what you want. You can change the format as desired.

Comment: If you could mark the questions as answered by clicking the check mark underneat the upvote/downvote arrows next to the answer, it will help future generations. Glad it worked for you!